# WPF waiting message while rendering a template

Tags: wpf, treeview, datatemplate

In my legacy project I've a treeview and an OnClick event binded on treeview leafs. Basically each time I choose a leaf, I get the node type and I apply a template into a control such:

```
gridDati.Template = Resources["tmplBit"] as ControlTemplate;
```

The "tmplBit" is a DataTemplate with several columns. All works fine but sometimes when I have 20 columns and 30/40 records, it takes time (4/5 sec) while applying the chosen template. 
I would like to show a waiting message, or something like that but I cannot find how. I've already a window that show a waiting message, I tried to use as:

```
    var aboutBox = new winWaitingMessage(Global.LM.T("@_3261_Inizio export"));
    aboutBox.Show();

    // Template?
    gridDati.Template = Resources["tmplBit"] as ControlTemplate;

    aboutBox.Close();
```

but the box is closed immediately, so I cannot find an event that tell me when the template is applied and rendered. Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

The framework provides no such event but you could handle the `Loaded` event for an element in the template and close the window when this event occurs, e.g.:

```
gridDati.Template = Resources["tmplBit"] as ControlTemplate;
gridDati.ApplyTemplate();
FrameworkElement fe = gridDati.Template.FindName("YourElement", gridDati) as FrameworkElement;
if (fe == null)
{
    aboutBox.Close();  
}
else
{
    void Fe_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        aboutBox.Close();
        fe.Loaded -= Fe_Loaded;
    }
    fe.Loaded += Fe_Loaded;
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="tmplBit">
    ...
    <Button x:Name="YourElement" ... />
```

Edit: If you don't want to or can't use a [local function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions) for whatever reason, you could use a lambda expression to achieve the same thing:

```
...
else
{
    RoutedEventHandler loadedHandler = null;
    loadedHandler = (s, e) =>
    {
        aboutBox.Close();
        fe.Loaded -= loadedHandler;
    };
    fe.Loaded += loadedHandler;
}
```

Comment: Mmmhh, sounds weird to me, how can you declare a method inside an if?

Comment: @Spaccaspecchi: It's called a local function and was introduced in C# 7.0: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions

Comment: I see but I'm still using .NET 4.5

Comment: @Spaccaspecchi: You can still use C# 7.0. Or simply don't use a local function but a lambda expression. See my edit for an example.

Comment: @Spaccaspecchi: Please remember to accept the answer and vote it up if your issue has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

you can use task

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern IntPtr FindWindow(IntPtr hwnd, string title);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern int PostMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, uint wParam, uint lParam);
        public const int WM_CLOSE = 0x10; 

        public const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;

        public const int WM_KEYUP = 0x0101;

        public const int VK_RETURN = 0x0D;


        private   void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Task task1 = new Task(() => 
            {

                   gridDati.Template = Resources["tmplBit"] as ControlTemplate;

            });
            task1.Start();
            Task cwt = task1.ContinueWith(t=>
            {
                FindAndKillWindow("Warning");
            });
            MessageBox.Show("Waiting...", "Warning");        
        }

        private static void FindAndKillWindow(string title)
        {
            IntPtr ptr = FindWindow(IntPtr.Zero, title);
            if (ptr != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                int ret = PostMessage(ptr, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);

                ptr = FindWindow(IntPtr.Zero, title);
                if (ptr != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    PostMessage(ptr, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_RETURN, 0);
                    PostMessage(ptr, WM_KEYUP, VK_RETURN, 0);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: It doesn't work, the messagebox get killed before the entire render of the datagrid. I'm still tring to find an event which gave me the moment of complete rendering of my control